# Java- While loop check if variable changes between two iterations

Tags: java, while-loop

Is it at all possible to check if a String variable has changed since any two iterations of a while loop?

```
while (true) {    
    String player=json_obj.getString("username");
    System.out.println("Found Player "+player);
}
```

My reasoning for this is that a I don't want to keep printing out the player variable if it hasn't changed between each iteration of the while loop.

EDIT*
Not sure why my post would receive a down vote since this is a valid question.
*

Comment: You could add a "player in last iteration" variable that you compare with and which you fill after each iteration step.

Comment: `String`s are immutable in Java, so you can't change it other than changing the object memory allocation segment that it points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thats quite easy:

```
String oldValue = "";
while (true)
{
    String player=json_obj.getString("username");
    if (!oldValue.equals(player))
    {
        System.out.println("Found Player "+player);
        break; // quit loop when player found?
    }
    oldValue = player
}
```

When you're trying to wait for a value to change there are better ways (`wait`, and `notify` for example). If you want to do this anyhow think about not making the loop "busy waiting" with small sleeps at the end of every iteration

Answer (score 2):

Keep the previous value of `player` in another variable, and compare them :

```
String oldPlayer="";
while (true) {    
    String player = json_obj.getString("username");
    if (!player.equals(oldPlayer)) {
        System.out.println("Found Player "+player);
        oldPlayer = player;
    }
}
```

This is assuming your actual loop contains more logic, since based on the code you posted this loop will never end, and `json_obj.getString("username")` will always return the same value.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct regarding how to do such checking.

But they are missing one **crucial** point: you don't just put down a while loop like

```
while (true) {
  String newValue = ...
  if (!newValue.equals(oldValue)) {...
}
```

without a **sleep** statement! The point is that any modern CPU can call that method to "get" the value zillions of time per second. But there is no point in doing that - because that simply pushes you to 100% CPU usage. Instead, you should allow for some time inbetween such calls.

And beyond that: I just *assume* that you have other code running in some other thread that actually changes those strings? If not, the above code will loop forever!